# how to extract string part and ignore number in jquery?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string like `foobar1, foobaz2, barbar23, nobar100` I want only `foobar, foobaz, barbar, nobar` and ignoring the number part.

Comment: I don't think this has much to do with jQuery - that is a javascript framework for DOM manipulation. You're doing string parsing, everything you need is in the javascript language.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to strip out things that are digits, a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp) can do that for you:

```
var s = "foobar1";
s = s.replace(/\d/g, "");
alert(s);
// "foobar"
```

(`\d` is the regex class for "digit". We're replacing them with nothing.)

Note that as given, it will remove *any* digit *anywhere* in the string.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in JavaScript:

```
/^[^\d]+/.exec("foobar1")[0]
```

This will return all characters from the beginning of string until a number is found.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = 'foobar1, foobaz2, barbar23, nobar100';
console.log(str.replace(/\d/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

Find some more information about regular expressions in javascript...

This should do what you want:

```
var re = /[0-9]*/g;
var newvalue= oldvalue.replace(re,"");
```

This replaces al numbers in the entire string. If you only want to remove at the end then use this:

```
var re = /[0-9]*$/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do that in JQuery, but in JavaScript you can just use a regular expression string replace.

```
var yourString = "foobar1, foobaz2, barbar23, nobar100";    
var yourStringMinusDigits = yourString.replace(/\d/g,"");
```